# Website names of Sitecore Commerce web applications

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation

Sitecore Commerce 9.0.1 is install on my machine and I want to install Sitecore Commerce 9.0.2 also on the same machine.

When we install Sitecore Commerce, it create few websites on IIS like CommerceAuthoring_Sc9, CommerceMinions_Sc9, CommerceOps_Sc9, CommerceShops_Sc9, SitecoreBizFx and SitecoreIdentityServer.

Since I want to install the Sitecore Commerce 9.0.2 also on the same machine, I must have to provide different name of the above mentioned web application which get created automatically. Please can somebody guide me how to provide custom name of these web applications.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change the default IIS site names, you can pass an additional parameter called **CommerceServicesPostfix** in Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1 when installing the Master_SingleServer.json configuration via SIF.

Inside the downloaded installation package for Sitecore XC9, you will find SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.2.14\Configuration\Commerce\Master_SingleServer.json. If you have a peek in there, by default the value of CommerceServicesPostfix is "Sc9". You can also change this default value to something else.

Note that if you change this value, you also need to update the default value of CommerceServicesPostfix parameter in the following files:

- SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.2.14\Configuration\Commerce\CommerceEngine\CommerceEngine.Deploy.json
- SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.2.14\Configuration\Commerce\CommerceEngine\CommerceEngine.Initialize.json

Comment: Thanks. What about for the SitecoreIdentityServer ?